# How to add ssl to mail subdomain of website?

Tags: email, ssl, subdomain, addition

I have one personel website for blogging. I added ssl from sslforfree. I added just my domain but I cant add to my mail subdomain.

For example, my domain is "website.com" I added this domain. But I cant add to my mail subdomain.

How can I add ssl to my mail subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Get issued with "*.website.com"
In the form of regular expression, it can be applied to any sub-domains.

#### Wildcard SSL Certificates [ssl-for-free](https://www.sslforfree.com/)

Wildcard certificates allow you to secure any sub-domains under a domain. If you want to secure any sub-domains of example.org that you have now or in the future you can make a wildcard certificate. To generate wildcard certificates, add an asterisk to the beginning of the domain(s) followed by a period. Wildcard certificates will also secure the root domain, so there is no need to re-enter the root domain in the process. For example, to create a wildcard domain for example.org, enter *.example.org. If you need certificates for multiple domains, such as example.org and example.com, you will need to create a separate wildcard certificate for each domain. Domain verification will be required for each domain.

Comment: Do you have know one website that give free wildcard certificate? Also, thanks for your response to my question.